# 302 error when using core_course_get_courses function from Moodle API

Tags: php, api, web-services, moodle

So I am trying to create a web service that will pull all of the courses from the moodle database using `core_course_get_courses`.

However every time that I run my script I get an error saying:

```
302 Found
nginx
```

This output is surrounded by HTML.

I know that a 302 error is a temporary redirect that is not working. However, when I test my API by typing it in as a URL. It works and spits out all of the required information that I need.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once('curl.php');

$token= '<I put my token in here>';
$domainName= '<I put my domain in here>';
$functionName= 'core_course_get_courses';
$serverUrl= $domainName . "/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=" . $token . "&wsfunction=" . $functionName;

$option['ids']='';
$options=array($option);
$params=array($options);

$curl= new curl;

$restFormat= '&moodlewsrestformat=json';

$resp= $curl->post($serverUrl . $restFormat, $params);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

I have checked my token numerous times: it's correct.

All of my other web services are working fine. I have created a few for `core_user_create_users` and `enrol_manual_enrol_users`.

My question is two-fold: Why is it working in the browser and not from my script?

and

How do I make my script work?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem with this.

In some web services 'https://' is not required and in some there are. In this specific instance, it is required and I was not including it in my domain name.

I also redid my array structure to look like this:

```
$option['ids']=array();
$options['options' => $option];
$params=$options;
```

If the array structure doesn't match perfectly, moodle will throw an error looking for the correct index.